# Unable to export to excel using json data with xlsx using angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, xlsx, exceljs

I am unable to export an array of object to excel sheet with **xlsx library** using angular 8. here is my sample code to export json data to excel with multiple sheets.

inside my app.html file.

`<button (click)="exportAsXLSX()" >Export to Excel </button>`

inside my app.ts file.

```
  public exportAsXLSX():void {
    let myExcelData = {teams: [{name: 'chelsea', matchsAvailable: 10},
                           {name: 'manu', matchsAvailable: 10},
                          {name: 'spurs', matchsAvailable: 10}, 
                          {name: 'arsenal', matchsAvailable: 10}],
                   Managers: [{team: 'chelsea', name: 'lampard'},
                              {team: 'manu', name: 'ole'}, 
                              {team: 'spurs', name: 'jose'}, 
                             {team: 'arsenal', name: 'wenger'},]}
    this.exportToExcelService.exportAsExcelFile(myExcelData , 'intelligence');
}
```

inside my service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
const EXCEL_EXTENSION = '.xlsx';
const EXCEL_TYPE = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ExportToExcelService {
  constructor() { }
  public exportAsExcelFile(json: any[], excelFileName: string): void {
    
    const worksheetForTeam: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json['teams']);
    const worksheetForManagers: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json['Managers']);
    const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { 'Sheet1': worksheetForTeam 'Sheet2': worksheetForManagers}, SheetNames: ['ByTheTeam', 'ByTheManagers'] };
    const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
    this.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, excelFileName);
  }
  private saveAsExcelFile(buffer: any, fileName: string): void {
    const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], {
      type: EXCEL_TYPE
    });
    FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + '_export_' + new Date().getTime() + EXCEL_EXTENSION);
  }
}
```

if i do these for a single sheet its working not for multiple sheets. i am able download excel files with sheets. But the sheets are empty without any data inside them.

Any insight where i am making mistake will be really helpful. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { 'ByTheTeam': worksheetForTeam 'ByTheManagers': worksheetForManagers}, SheetNames: ['ByTheTeam', 'ByTheManagers'] };
```

changing the sheet name worked for me. simple **noob** mistake.